# Firefox Vs Chrome from web developers prespective

Tags: javascript, web-services, firefox, google-chrome

I hope I am asking a question that fits Stack Overflow standards. I am curious to know from web developers point of view, what do you prefer Firefox or Google Chrome. Is Firefox or chrome your best choice of developing web apps and websites. Which one do you prefer and why.

Comment: I am closing this. This is why: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Firefox, as I find it easier thanks mainly to the Web Developer add-on, and a few others.  Interestingly, a [recently-leaked Google document](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/16-insights-into-googles-rating-guidelines) for internal testers said they had to use Firefox.

Comment: But web developer toolbar is available for chrome too

Comment: Google content raters aren't the same thing as internal testers :)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome, its built in dev tools are easily as powerful as Firebug, yet no need for an extension.

http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html

Chrome also loads up within a few seconds, while Firefox still takes an age to startup, that really bugs me!